# How do I read a log files where separation between two objects is nothing?

Tags: python, database, validation

I have a log files which I want to read to a dataframe, but there is no separator between two objects.

`Country|ID|Item_IDCountry|ID|Item_IDCountry|ID|Item_IDCountry|ID|Item_ID`

it is in this format where Country is strictly a 2 char string.

I'm trying to figure out how to do it in python as i'm still a beginner.
Any help would be much appreciated

I tried read_csv but that was a fail, I tried to look for answers online but didnt find much

Comment: Are the items in the logfile fixed-width?

Comment: Can you give us an example of a row please

Comment: Can you show couple of lines in the log?

Comment: 384361666|1091293960|NL
146998538|1091293960|NL
1801980088|1091293960|NL
1738705827|1091293960|NL
1622793002|1091293960|NL
1134415000|1091293960|NL
2052613843|1091293960|NL
49660895|1091293960|NL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seperator in that format is `|`, and assuming the name of the log file in question is `logs.csv`:

```py
import pandas

logs = []
with open("logs.csv") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    column_names = lines[0].rstrip('\n').split("|")
    for l in lines[1:]:
        logs.append(l.rstrip('\n').split("|"))

df = pandas.DataFrame(logs, columns=column_names)
print(df)
```

`lines[0].rstrip('\n').split("|")` basically removes the new-line character from the first line and turns the column names (`Country|ID|Item_IDCountry|ID|Item_IDCountry|ID|Item_IDCountry|ID|Item_ID`) into a list.

`for l in lines[1:]:` iterates over all lines in the logs file, starting for the second line.

Comment: This is kinda what I needed, I did sort the problem thanks to this. thank you very much!